# Efficient item binning algorithm (itertools/numpy)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I think this is a common combinatorics problem, but I can't seem to find a name for it or any material about it. I am doing this in Python and numpy, but if there is a fast matrix method for this, I can probably translate.

Basically, given *n* items, I need to generate all ways to put them in *m* bins. As an example, binning 4 items into 3 bins would give something like `[(4, 0, 0), (3, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1), (2, 2, 0), (2, 1, 1), ...]`. This is a product with a fixed total.

Implementing this with itertools is straightforward.

```
import itertools

def fixed_total_product(bins, num_items):
""" Return iterator of all item binning possibilities. """
return itertools.ifilter(lambda combo: sum(combo) == num_items,
                         itertools.product(xrange(num_items + 1), repeat=bins))
```

Unfortunately, I think doing subsequent calculations in loops will be inefficient. Working with this as a 2D numpy array would be faster later on, but I can't figure out an efficient way to build an array with this. I could iterate over the ifilter result, building a list of the possibilities, and use this to construct the array, but that seems like a huge waste.

I'm guessing the best way to do this is to build everything "the numpy way", but I'm not sure how to do this. There is a speedy product implementation on stackoverflow: [Using numpy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays). I'm guessing you can modify this only to output products with the right sum. The size of the array should be ((m-1) + n) choose n, since there are m-1 bin boundaries.

Any ideas? Benchmarks much appreciated, but not required.

Comment: I mentioned [the integer partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) which gives the length of a similar sequence. I don't think it's far off though, because once you have that integer partition sequence it's easy to remove the order (add all permutations) and enforce a number of bins (`m` in `n` bins means that the biggest number in any bin can be at most `m-n`).

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought I had seen solved/closed before. I have to disagree about the solution though. I added a docstring and more descriptive vars to help understand the algorithm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the recursion C(n, k) = C(n - 1, k) + C(n - 1, k - 1), memoized, using numpy operations.

```
import numpy as np

def binnings(n, k, cache={}):
    if n == 0:
        return np.zeros((1, k))
    if k == 0:
        return np.empty((0, 0))
    args = (n, k)
    if args in cache:
        return cache[args]
    a = binnings(n - 1, k, cache)
    a1 = a + (np.arange(k) == 0)
    b = binnings(n, k - 1, cache)
    b1 = np.hstack((np.zeros((b.shape[0], 1)), b))
    result = np.vstack((a1, b1))
    cache[args] = result
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print timeit.timeit('binnings(20, 5, {})', setup='from __main__ import binnings', number=1)
```

Time in seconds for (20, 5):

```
0.0129251480103
```

Comment: Legendary dude. Thanks a ton. I will edit the question when I come back to this.

Answer (score 3):

There probably is a faster way using a few different tricks in numpy. `numpy.indices` is where you want to start. It's essentially the equivalent of `itertools.product`, once you combine it with `rollaxis`.  Sven Marnach's answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709510/itertools-product-speed-up) is an excellent example of this (There's a minor error in his last example, however, which is what you want to use. It should be `numpy.indices((len(some_list) + 1), * some_length...`)

However, for something like this, it's likely to be more readable using itertools.

`numpy.fromiter` is a bit faster than explicitly converting things to a list, especially if you give it a count of the number of items in the iterator. The main advantage is that is uses considerably less memory, which can be very helpful in the case of large iterators.

Here are some examples using both the `numpy.indices` trick and various ways of converting the iterator to a numpy array:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import scipy.special


def fixed_total_product(bins, num_items):
    return itertools.ifilter(lambda combo: sum(combo) == num_items,
            itertools.product(xrange(num_items + 1), repeat=bins))

def fixed_total_product_fromiter(bins, num_items):
    size = scipy.special.binom(bins - 1 + num_items, num_items)
    combinations = fixed_total_product(bins, num_items)
    indicies = (idx for row in combinations for idx in row)
    arr = np.fromiter(indicies, count=bins * int(size), dtype=np.int)
    return arr.reshape(-1, bins)

def fixed_total_product_fromlist(bins, num_items):
    return np.array(list(fixed_total_product(bins, num_items)), dtype=np.int)

def fixed_total_product_numpy(bins, num_items):
    arr = np.rollaxis(np.indices((num_items + 1,) * bins), 0, bins + 1)
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, bins)
    arr = np.arange(num_items + 1)[arr]
    sums = arr.sum(axis=1)
    return arr[sums == num_items]

m, n = 5, 20

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    list_time = timeit.timeit('fixed_total_product_fromlist(m, n)',
            setup='from __main__ import fixed_total_product_fromlist, m, n',
            number=1)
    iter_time = timeit.timeit('fixed_total_product_fromiter(m, n)',
            setup='from __main__ import fixed_total_product_fromiter, m, n',
            number=1)
    numpy_time = timeit.timeit('fixed_total_product_numpy(m, n)',
            setup='from __main__ import fixed_total_product_numpy, m, n',
            number=1)

    print 'All combinations of {0} items drawn from a set of {1} items...'.format(m,n)
    print '  Converting to a list and then an array: {0} sec'.format(list_time)
    print '  Using fromiter: {0} sec'.format(iter_time)
    print '  Using numpy.indices: {0} sec'.format(numpy_time)
```

As for timing:

```
All combinations of 5 items drawn from a set of 20 items...
  Converting to a list and then an array: 2.75901389122 sec
  Using fromiter: 2.10619592667 sec
  Using numpy.indices: 1.44955015182 sec
```

You'll notice that none of them are particularly fast.

You're using a brute-force algorithm (generate all possible combinations and then filter them), and I'm just copying it in the numpy-based example here.

There is probably a much more efficient way to do this! However, I'm not a CS or math person by any means, so I don't know if there's a well-known algorithm to do this without generating all possible combinations first...

Good luck, at any rate!

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm reviving a pretty old thread here, but I hope a good solution will be still appreciated (even if not by the OP anymore).

The problem itself is akin to representing multivariate polynomials in code. Think e.g. (corresponding to the example with 4 items in 3 bins) of the polynomial you get from expanding `(x+y+z)^4` which is something like `x^4*y^0*z^0 + 4*x^3*y^1*z^0 + ...` and the exponents to x, y, and z are the elements of the array:

```
[4,0,0],
[3,1,0],
[3,0,1],
[2,2,0],
[2,1,1],
[2,0,2],
[1,3,0],
[
```

If you look closely, you see that e.g. the elements to the right of the `3` are the exponents of `(y+z)^1`, to the right of `2` are the exponents of `(y+z)^2` and so on. More general, to the right of `p` you have the exponents of `(y+z)^(4-p)`. This indicates some recursive structure: Let's say e(m,p) indicates the exponents for `m` variables (=bins) and `p` total exponent (=items), then you get all of them by choosing the first exponent `q` from `0` to `p`, and the exponents of the remaining `m-1` variables are given by `e(m-1,p-q)`.

In `python` with `numpy` you can formulate that like this:

```py
def multiindex_exact(m, p):
    if m == 0:
        return np.zeros((1 if p==0 else 0, 0), np.int8)
    else:
        I = np.zeros((0, m), np.int8)
        for q in reversed(range(0, p + 1)):
            J = multiindex_exact(m - 1, p - q)
            Jn = np.full((J.shape[0], 1), q)
            I = np.vstack((I, np.hstack((Jn, J))))
        return I
```

Of course, you can make that more efficient by precalculating array sizes, and filling in the values directly.

If you need to distribute not exactly, but *a maximum* of `p` items into `m` bins, so that the sum over the bins is always `<=p`, you can use the following similar code.

```py
def multiindex_lower(m, p):
    if m == 0:
        return np.zeros((1, 0), np.int8)
    else:
        I = np.zeros((0, m), np.int8)
        for q in range(0, p + 1):
            J = multiindex_lower(m - 1, q)
            Jn = q - J.sum(1).reshape((J.shape[0], 1))
            I = np.vstack((I, np.hstack((J, Jn))))
        return I
```