# How to use NumPy to directly create an a array that is made up of a few python nested loop of a uniform sized tuple/list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a tuple/list like so:

```
tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
f = [ (e, d, c, b, a) for a in tup for b in tup for c in tup for d in tup for e in tup ]
```

How do I create an equivalent array directly from NumPy without using `np.array( f )`? Is there some slicing technique that I should use on `tup`? Is what I am asking for possible?

I am specifically asking if NumPy can do this directly, for e.g via some slicing technique or some NumPy function, without using other python functions. I am trying to better understand the capabilities of NumPy.

Thank you.

Comment: Would itertools work : `np.array(list(itertools.product(tup,repeat=5)))`?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. I know `itertools.product` can be used to create `f`, but it isn't specifically what I am asking for.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684492/numpy-equivalent-of-itertools-product

Comment: From linked Q&A, use `cartesian_product_transpose(*([np.arange(1,6)]*5))`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use itertools.

```
import itertools
tup = (1,2,3,4,5)
list(itertools.product(tup, repeat=5))
```

Comment: Thank you but this answer is not what I am looking for. I am specifically asking if numpy can do this directly, for e.g via some slicing technique for some numpy function. I will clarify this requirement in my question.