# Build cartesian product using itertools in python fast

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I am using  **itertools** to do **cartesian products** of **list of lists**.

**list of lists :-**

```
[['who','what'],['is','in'],['age','ago']]
```

**Piece of Code:-**

```
from itertools import product
[' '.join(p) for p in product(*temp_suggest_lst)]
```

I am using this **itertools** to do **cartesian product**. Sometimes my each list contains **100000** of values/string then **itertools** might be **slow down**.

*Is there any tools which build cartesian product very very fast or itertools is the best?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [itertools product speed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709510/itertools-product-speed-up)

Comment: @KasraAD : I am not using numpy. I have simple list in python.