# Binomial iterated expectation in Cython

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, cython

I am brand new to Cython. How to convert the Python function called Values below to Cython? With factors=2 and i=60 this takes 2.8 secs on my big Linux box. The goal is sub 1 sec with factors=2 and i=360.

Here's the code. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

class Numeraire:
    def __init__(self, rate):
        self.rate = rate
    def __call__(self, timenext, time, state):
        return np.exp(-self.rate*(timenext - time))

def Values(values, i1, i0=0, numeraire=Numeraire(0.)):
    factors=len(values.shape)
    norm=0.5**factors
    for i in np.arange(i1-1, i0-1, -1):
        for j in itertools.product(np.arange(i+1), repeat=factors):
            value = 0.
            for k in itertools.product(np.arange(2), repeat=factors):
                value += values[tuple(np.array(j) + np.array(k))]
            values[j] = value*norm*numeraire(i+1, i, j)
    return values

factors = 2
i = 60
values = np.ones([i+1]*factors)
Values(values, i, numeraire=Numeraire(0.05/12))
print values[(0,)*factors], np.exp(-0.05/12*i)
```

Comment: You should probably try to use standard NumPy vectorized operations before bringing in Cython. In particular, you'll pretty quickly be bottlenecked by `numeraire` unless you start computing that in a vectorized manner or move it into Cython as well.

Comment: I think you'd get a lot more help if you explained what this code does, including the effects on a small array.  With your sample, `values` is smallest in the upper left corner, and increases in 'circles' to 1 on the right and bottom.  Why?

Comment: Because it's attempting to implement a binomial lattice, used in option pricing. Here's a reference: http://www.investopedia.com/features/eso/eso3.asp

Answer (score 2):

Before using Cython, you should optimize your code with Numpy. Here, vectorizing the third and second inner `for` loops, yields a x40 speed-up,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import itertools
   ...: 
   ...:  # define Numaire and Values functions from the question above
   ...:
   ...: def Values2(values, i1, i0=0, numeraire=Numeraire(0.)):
   ...:     factors=len(values.shape)
   ...:     norm=0.5**factors
   ...:     k = np.array(list(itertools.product(np.arange(2), repeat=factors)))
   ...:     for i in np.arange(i1-1, i0-1, -1):
   ...:         j = np.array(list(itertools.product(np.arange(i+1), repeat=factors)))
   ...:         mask_all = j[:,:,np.newaxis] + k.T[np.newaxis, :, :]
   ...:         mask_x, mask_y = np.swapaxes(mask_all, 2, 1).reshape(-1, 2).T
   ...:      
   ...:         values_tmp = values[mask_x, mask_y].reshape((j.shape[0], k.shape[0]))
   ...:         values_tmp = values_tmp.sum(axis=1)
   ...:         values[j[:,0], j[:,1]] = values_tmp*norm*numeraire(i+1, i, j)
   ...:     return values
   ...:
   ...: factors = 2
   ...: i = 60
   ...: values = lambda : np.ones([i+1]*factors)
   ...: print values()[(0,)*factors], np.exp(-0.05/12*i)
   ...:
   ...: res = Values(values(), i, numeraire=Numeraire(0.05/12))
   ...: res2 = Values2(values(), i, numeraire=Numeraire(0.05/12))
   ...: np.testing.assert_allclose(res, res2)
   ...:
   ...: %timeit  Values(values(), i, numeraire=Numeraire(0.05/12))
   ...: %timeit  Values2(values(), i, numeraire=Numeraire(0.05/12))
   ...:
1.0 0.778800783071
1 loops, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 31.8 ms per loop
```

The next step would be to replace the line,

```
j = np.array(list(itertools.product(np.arange(i+1), repeat=factors)
```

with it's Numpy equivalent, taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714857/1791279) (not very pretty),

```
def itertools_product_numpy(some_list, some_length):
    return some_list[np.rollaxis(
          np.indices((len(some_list),) * some_length), 0, some_length + 1)
    .reshape(-1, some_length)]

k = itertools_product_numpy(np.arange(i+1), factors)
```

this result in an overall x160 speed up and the code runs in 1.2 second on my laptop for `i=360` and `factors = 2`.

In this last version, I don't think that you will get much speed up, if you port it to Cython, since there is just one loop remaining and it has only ~360 iterations. Rather, some fine-tuned Python/Numpy optimizations should be performed to get a further speed increase.

Alternatively, you can try applying Cython to your original implementation. However because it is based on `itertools.product`, which is slow when called repeatedly in a loop, Cython will not help there.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your wonderful answer! On my machine your solution runs in 1.4 sec! Sorry to be greedy but, can your function be modified to allow the factors = 1 case, for example?

Comment: @SteveSchulist  Aww, yes  sorry, I have not realized to that `values` has `factors` columns, this was indeed done for the case `factors=2` (i.e. 2D array) and would need to be generalized to  ND arrays (or at least 1D). Unfortunately, I don't think I could look into this week though...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my latest answer (no Cython!), which runs in 125 msec for the `factor=2`, `i=360` case.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

slices = (slice(None, -1, None), slice(1, None, None))

def Expectation(values, numeraire, i, i0=0):
    def Values(values, i):
        factors = values.ndim
        expect = np.zeros((i,)*factors)
        for j in itertools.product(slices, repeat=factors):
            expect += values[j]
        return expect*0.5**factors*numeraire(i, i-1)
    return reduce(Values, range(i, i0, -1), values)

class Numeraire:
    def __init__(self, factors, rate=0):
        self.factors = factors
        self.rate = rate
    def __call__(self, timenext, time):
        return np.full((time+1,)*factors, np.exp(-self.rate*(timenext - time)))

factors = 2
i = 360
values, numeraire = np.ones((i+1,)*factors), Numeraire(factors, 0.05/12)
%timeit Expectation(values, numeraire, i)
Expectation(values, numeraire, i)[(0,)*factors], np.exp(-0.05/12*i)
```