# Efficient implementation for generating all combinations of elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, cartesian-product

In numpy there is an efficient solution for generating the [cartesian product of two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608701/348501) using `meshgrid`.

Is there a ready-made solution for getting the combinations of all elements in a single vector as per `{x_i, x_j : 1 <= i <= j <= N}` where `N` is the length of the vector?

Illustration: Let us asume:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Output should ideally be two vectors that together form the combination of all elements of the input:

```
output1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
output2 = [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]
```

I know how to implement this with python loops but I was looking for a faster solution.

Also: Does this form of combination have a name?

Comment: Maybe answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709510/itertools-product-speed-up is what you're looking for.

Comment: @GasperStukelj For a normal cartesian product yes. What I am looking for is a "semi-cartesian product" though. If a cartesian product can be thought of as a matrix, my problem would be like a triangular matrix.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for link. I was already considering using numpy. Very nice to have a ready-made solution!