# Internals of Python list, access and resizing runtimes

Tags: python, list, time, space, internals

Is Python's `[]` a list or an array?
Is the access time of an index O(1) like an array or O(n) like a list?
Is appending/resizing O(1) like a list or O(n) like an array, or is it a hybrid that can manage O(1) for accessing and resizing?

I [read here](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html) that array access is really slow in Python. However, when I wrote a memoized version of a recursive fibonacci procedure using both a dictionary (Python's dictionary is suppose to be really fast) and a list, they had equal times. Why is this?

Does a Python tuple have faster access times than a python list?

Comment: Don't you mean "linked list" instead every time you mention "list" in your question?

Comment: "I read here that array access is really slow in Python." - This was very out of date even when this question was originally asked. It's also talking about constant-factor overhead, while the question here is about big-O complexity. (Also, that source **directly said** - which was true in 2000, true in 2011, and true today - that `list` access is O(1); so it's hard to understand why the question was asked.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Python's `[]` is implemented as an *array*, not a linked list. Although resizing is O(n), appending to it is *amortized O(1)*, because resizes happen very rarely. If you're not familiar with how this works, read this [Wikipedia entry on dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). Python's list doesn't expand by a factor of 2 each time, it's a bit more complicated than that, but the expansions are still designed to make appending amortized O(1).

Inserting in the middle, however, is always an inefficient O(n), because `n` items may have to be moved.

Tuples aren't faster than lists - they're just immutable lists under the hood (*).

Regarding your dictionary test: depending on your exact implementation, caching in a list will be faster than with a dict. However, Python's dicts are highly optimized, and especially for small amounts of keys will perform great.

---

(*) Here's a list's "get item" C function in Python 2.6:

```
PyObject *
PyList_GetItem(PyObject *op, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    if (!PyList_Check(op)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    if (i < 0 || i >= Py_SIZE(op)) {
        if (indexerr == NULL)
            indexerr = PyString_FromString(
                "list index out of range");
        PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_IndexError, indexerr);
        return NULL;
    }
    return ((PyListObject *)op) -> ob_item[i];
}
```

And this is a tuple's:

```
PyObject *
PyTuple_GetItem(register PyObject *op, register Py_ssize_t i)
{
    if (!PyTuple_Check(op)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    if (i < 0 || i >= Py_SIZE(op)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "tuple index out of range");
        return NULL;
    }
    return ((PyTupleObject *)op) -> ob_item[i];
}
```

As you can see, they're almost exactly the same. In the end, after some type and bound checking, it's a simple pointer access with an index.

[Reference: [Python documentation on Time Complexity for data type operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)]

Comment: +1 for giving a much better and much more detailed explanation!

Comment: "Python's list doesn't expand by a factor of 2 each time, it's a bit more complicated than that, but the expansions are still designed to make appending amortized O(1)." can you point out a ressource that explains how the factor is actually determined ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 10):

There is a great list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) outlining the time complexity of the python data types.  In your case item retrieval should be O(1) time.

Answer (score 2):

Python's list is comparable to [ArrayList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) of Java. The [access time](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for getting an item from both list and tuple should `O(1)`. Norvig's article points out that Python's list is comparable to Vector in Java or Adjustable Array in Lisp and you really need more space, but the access time is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples *are* faster than lists. I don't know the underlying implementation. I read that in 'Dive into Python' at some point :)  The relevant excerpt:

"Tuples are faster than lists. If you're defining a constant set of values and all you're ever going to do with it is iterate through it, use a tuple instead of a list."

Comment: For access, yes, you're right. Apologies :). I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python which seems to suggest it depends on the operation in question.

Comment: That answer isn't very accurate, because it builds a constant list from scratch - which is what takes more time. This however isn't a common operation in real code. Once you have a list, there is no difference.