# Difference beetween C arrays and Python lists

Tags: python, c, arrays, list

I ask this because i'm a beginner in CS and i have this doubt. So it would be nice if peeps try to explain instead of just make humor or downvote. I tought this site was for learning from others.

Is just a different name or there something different underlying it?

Can anyone briefly explain the difference beetween C arrays and Python lists?

Comment: Try to remove an element from inside a c array

Comment: Possible [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use)

Comment: [How are lists implemented?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented)

Comment: Try this: `if not any(c in "array" for c in "list"): print("completely different")`

Comment: Basically, Python lists are C arrays with associated length informations (to permit resizing them).

Comment: Python is written in c, so maybe you should ask "[How is Python's List Implemented?][1]".


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented

Comment: This response to another recent question might be helpful in giving you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/21511293/1230086

Comment: @Cuz When you move your mouse on the down-vote button a pop-up says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". So, if somebody thinks that one of the three applies, he will down-vote.

Comment: Stack overflow is also not about guilting people into helping you. Over half your question is preamble and contributes nothing.

Comment: *boggle* If you think stack overflow sucks, then why are you using the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python `list` is essentially an array of object references that keeps track of how many elements it contains.

(Conceptually, a Python reference is somewhat similar to a C pointer.)

Read more here: [Internals of Python list, access and resizing runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932328/internals-of-python-list-access-and-resizing-runtimes)