# Why do lists with the same data have different sizes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-internals

Say I create python `lists` in two ways.

In the first case I use simple assignment:

```
my_list = []
print(my_list, '->', my_list.__sizeof__())
my_list = [1]
print(my_list, '->', my_list.__sizeof__())
my_list = [1, 1]
print(my_list, '->', my_list.__sizeof__())
```

In the second case I use `append()` method on list:

```
my_list = []
print(my_list, '->', my_list.__sizeof__())
my_list.append(1)
print(my_list, '->', my_list.__sizeof__())
my_list.append(1)
print(my_list, '->', my_list.__sizeof__())
```

But I get unexpected (for me) output:

```
=== WITH ASSIGNMENT ===
([], '->', 40)
([1], '->', 48)
([1, 1], '->', 56)
=== WITH APPEND ===
([], '->', 40)
([1], '->', 72)
([1, 1], '->', 72)
```

What happens internally with Python memory management? Why do the 'same' lists have different sizes?

Comment: I'd guess because when you create the list as a literal Python assigns the specific size needed, whereas when you append to it it expands more than required on the assumption that you won't just append once.

Comment: [internals of python list access and resizing runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932328/internals-of-python-list-access-and-resizing-runtimes)

Comment: Also related question: [list() uses more memory than list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018398/list-uses-more-memory-than-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you append to a list, memory is over-allocated to the list for **performance** reasons so that multiple appends would not require corresponding reallocations of memory for the list which would slow the overall performance in the case of repeated appends.

The CPython source clearly describes this behaviour in a [comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L50):

```c
/* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 * Note: new_allocated won't overflow because the largest possible value
 *       is PY_SSIZE_T_MAX * (9 / 8) + 6 which always fits in a size_t.
 */
```

In the other case, the list is constructed from a literal, and the size of the list reflects the size of the container itself and the references to each contained object.

The exact allocation behaviour may vary with other Python implementations (see `list.append` implementations for [Jython](https://github.com/jythontools/jython/blob/master/src/org/python/core/PyList.java#L533) and [PyPy](https://github.com/mozillazg/pypy/blob/dfa370c0d5e5613bbbb9c5934c3be4b4ad2c6607/pypy/module/cpyext/listobject.py#L89)) and over-allocation is not guaranteed to exist.