# Numpy array vs list of lists - editing values one by one (help implementing)

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I'm working with DNA sequence alignments and trying to implement a simple scoring algorithm. Since i have to use a matrix for the calculations, i thought numpy should be way faster than a list of lists, but as I tested both, the python lists seem to be way faster. I found this thread ([Why use numpy over list based on speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860970/why-use-numpy-over-list-based-on-speed/46868693)) but still; i'm using preallocated numpy vs preallocated lists and list of lists are the clear winners.
Here is my code:

**Lists**

```
def edirDistance(x, y):
    x_dim = len(x)+1
    y_dim = len(y)+1
    D = []
    for i in range(x_dim):
        D.append([0] * (y_dim))
    
    #Filling the matrix borders
    for i in range(x_dim):
        D[i][0] = i
    for i in range(y_dim):
        D[0][i] = i
    
    for i in range(1, x_dim):
        for j in range(1, y_dim):
            distHor = D[i][j-1] + 1
            distVer = D[i-1][j] + 1
            if x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1]
            else:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1] + 1
            D[i][j] = min(distHor, distVer,distDiag)
    return D
```

**Numpy**

```
def NP_edirDistance(x, y):
    x_dim = len(x)+1
    y_dim = len(y)+1
    D = np.zeros((x_dim,y_dim))
    
    #Filling the matrix borders
    for i in range(x_dim):
        D[i][0] = i
    for i in range(y_dim):
        D[0][i] = i
    
    for i in range(1, x_dim):
        for j in range(1, y_dim):
            distHor = D[i][j-1] + 1
            distVer = D[i-1][j] + 1
            if x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1]
            else:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1] + 1
            D[i][j] = min(distHor, distVer,distDiag)
    return D
```

I'm not timing the np import.

```
a = 'ACGTACGACTATCGACTAGCTACGAA'
b = 'ACCCACGTATAACGACTAGCTAGGGA'
```

```
%%time
edirDistance(a, b)
```

**total: 1.41 ms**

```
%%time
NP_edirDistance(a, b)
```

**total: 4.43 ms**

Replacing `D[i][j]` by `D[i,j]` greatly improved time, but still slower. (Thanks @Learning is a mess !)

**total: 2.64 ms**

I tested with even larger DNA sequences (around 10.000 letters each) and still lists are winning.

**Can someone help me improve timing?**

**Are lists better for this use?**

Comment: `numpy` arrays are fast - if you use the whole-array compiled methods.  When used iteratively like this, lists are faster.  Arrays are not a drop-in replacement.  You have to take time to learn how to use them effectively.  Otherwise stick with the lists.

Comment: As said by @hpaulj you are not using any vectorization here. Also try replacing each `D[i][j]` by `D[i,j]` for quicker look-ups and assigns.

Comment: Plus the zero padding can be done by `D[0] = 0; D[:,0] = 0` which is vectorized and faster than your two for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have faster run is to use GPU/TPU-aided accelerators such as numba and …. I have tested your codes by that `a` and `b` on google colab TPU without using accelerators:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 563 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.95 ms per loop    # NumPy
```

But with using **numba** as `nopython=True`, *without any changes to your codes*:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def edirDistance(x, y):
       .
       .

@nb.njit()
def NP_edirDistance(x, y):
       .
       .
```

It gets:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 213 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 153 µs per loop    # NumPy
```

Which will get significant difference between them using huge samples or by improving and vectorizing your NumPy codes. This method results as below for samples with 10000 length:

```
35.50053691864014
22.95994758605957    # NumPy (seconds)
```