# abbreviating a double comparison in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to abbreviate a comparison statement in python so that I don't have to write the whole thing out again? For example, instead of :

```
a=3
if a==3 or a==2:
    print "hello world"
```

could I do something like:
    if a==(3 or 2):
        print "hello world"

I know the above example won't work but is there another way i can achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 14):

```
if a in (2, 3):
  print "hello world"
```

Comment: Re your edit: is it preferable to use a tuple instead of a list?

Comment: @Levon: I don't have a strong preference either way, but to my eye a tuple looks slightly more natural here.

Comment: ok, thanks .. I know sometimes there are subtle differences, just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything as I generally use lists for this.

Comment: It's just a matter of style, but there is definitely a general principle that justifies preferring a tuple to a list: use more restricted tools when you can get away with it, and the powerful ones only when they're needed - that way, the reader of the code won't be distracted by thinking of functionality that won't actually be used. Here, use a tuple because you aren't going to use the list-specific functionality of modification in-place.

Comment: While it's probably unlikely that this would be a case where it matters, tuples are quite a bit faster to create than lists in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python

Answer (score 14):

Possible solutions, depending on what exactly you want:

- `if a in (2,3)`
- `if a in xrange(2, 4)`
- `if 2 <= a <= 3`

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `xrange` instead of `range` in this case? I'm so glad Python 3 did away with `xrange`.

Comment: @MarkRansom In this case it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @robert +1but if it doesn't matter it would be best to use range for py3x compatibility.

Comment: but range has to put a list in memory with all the numbers so
`3 in range(9999999999999)` raises an exception but `3 in xrange(9999999999999)` works

Answer (score 13):

See [Python 3.2 Optimizations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) regarding the reason for the answer below.

```
a = 3
if a in {2, 3}:
    print('Hello, world!')
```