# Assigning values to array slices is slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I'm trying to optimize a Python algorithm by implementing it in Cython. My question is regarding a certain performance bottleneck that exists in the following code:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
def anglesToRGB( np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] y, np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] x ):

cdef double angle
cdef double Hp
cdef double C
cdef double X
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3] res = np.zeros([y.shape[0], y.shape[1], 3], dtype=np.float64)

for i in xrange(y.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(y.shape[1]):
        angle = atan2( y[i,j], x[i,j] )*180.0/PI+180

        C = sqrt(pow(y[i,j],2)+pow(x[i,j],2))/360.0 #Chroma
        Hp = angle/60.0
        X = C*(1-fabs( Hp%2-1))

        C *= 255
        X *= 255

        if (0. <= Hp < 1.):
            res[i,j,:] = [C,X,0]
        elif (1. <= Hp < 2.):
            res[i,j,:] = [X,C,0]
        elif (2. <= Hp < 3.):
            res[i,j,:] = [0,C,X]
        elif (3. <= Hp < 4.):
            res[i,j,:] = [0,X,C]
        elif (4. <= Hp < 5.):
            res[i,j,:] = [X,C,C]
        else:
            res[i,j,:] = [C,0,X]

return res
```

I've identified the major bottleneck to be when i assign a list of values to a slice of the res array, 
like with

```
res[i,j,:] = [C,X,0]
```

However, if i change the assignment to

```
res[i,j,0] = C
res[i,j,1] = X
res[i,j,2] = 0
```

Then the code runs orders of magnitude faster.
To me this is strange because surely the Cython compiler should be smart enough to do this for me? Or do i need to provide it with some hints first?
I should note that changing the slicing to 0:3 instead of : and making the list of values a numpy array doesn't improve the performance.

What i'd like to know is why this operation is killing performance so badly and if there's any way to solve it without having to sacrifice the convenient list and slice notation.

Best regards

Comment: Could part of your issue be that `[C, X, 0]` causes python to allocate a new list? Perhaps using a tuple would be faster: `(C, X, 0)`

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: Arent tuples allocated too?

Comment: @Dietrich they are, but they are slightly more memory efficient and faster to assign. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: That only works for constant tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, Cython (tested with 0.17) isn't smart enough to optimize this slice assignment away. If you look at the generated C code (use `cython -a` and click any line in the HTML report to see the generated code), then you can see that

```
res[i,j,:] = [C,X,0]
```

is compiled to

- conversion between C and Python floating point types
- allocation of a list `[C,X,0]`
- allocation of a tuple `(i, j, slice(None))`
- a call to `res.__setitem__`
- error checks on all of these
- deallocation of the allocated structures

I.e., almost all the same things CPython would do to execute this code.

What you can do to get around this is:

1. Declare three variables, say `cdef double v1, v2, v3`;
2. assign to these in the conditionals, like `v1, v2, v3 = C, X, 0` etc., which is optimized to three C assignments;
3. after the conditional block, assign `v1, v2, v3` to `res[i,j,0]` etc. in three separate assignments.