# Does Python have a cleaner way to express "if x contains a|b|c|d..."?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, substring

The Pythonic way to check if a string `x` is a substring of `y` is:

```
if x in y:
```

Finding if `x` is equivalent to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` or `g` is also Pythonic:

```
if x in [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]:
```

But checking if some string `x` contains either `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` or `g` seems clunky:

```
if a in x or b in x or c in x or d in x or e in x or f in x or g in x
```

Is there a more **Pythonic** method of checking if a string `x` contains an element of a list?

I know it is trivial to write this myself using a loop or using a regex:

```
re.search('(dog|cat|bird|mouse|elephant|pig|cow)', x)
```

but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way that does not involve regex.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The Pythonic approach would be to use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(s in x for s in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)):
```

From the linked documentation:

> **`any`**(*iterable*)
>
> Return True if any element of the *iterable* is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

Also, notice that I've used a tuple instead of a list here. If your `a`-`g` values are pre-defined, then a tuple would indeed be preferred. See: [Are tuples more efficient than lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python)

Comment: Inner parenthesis aren't nessesary `any(s in x for s in a, b, c, d, e, f, g)` is fine.

Comment: @Igonato At least on Python 3 this is a syntax error.

Comment: @Igonato I find the inner parenthesis add readability.

Comment: You can also use `if any(s in x for s in "abcdefg")`, since a string is also iterable.

Comment: @chepner: You can't. a,b,c,.. are variables, not chars!

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that :)

Comment: This would be more efficient as `any(s in frozenset((a,b,c,d,e,f,g)) for s in x)` without changing readability much at all.

Comment: @CeasarBautista No, that's completely different. What you have checks if any of the characters of `x` are in the set `{a,...,g}`, which isn't what we want.

Comment: The Are tuples more efficient than lists in Python? link is great!

Answer (score 27):

```
if any(q in x for q in [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]):
```

I think that's about as short & Pythonic as you can get it.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late to the party, but

```
not frozenset(x).isdisjoint(frozenset(y))
```

would work, and may be faster (algorithmically, but maybe not for smaller test cases).

Comment: I find this one much harder to read.

Comment: this is rather obscure

Comment: @siledh not really, it's referenced in some other answers, and the fact that using `set` and similar types will reduce the lookup cost isn't too esoteric either.

Answer (score 3):

without using `any` but simply `max`

```
def is_in(symbol, lst):
    return max([symbol in x for x in lst]) 

print is_in('a',['ae','br','tl'])
print is_in('c',['ae','br','tl'])
```

gives

```
>>> 
True
False
```

Comment: It's faster as `max(...)` instead of `max([...])`.

Comment: It's much faster as `any(...)` instead of `max(...)`...

Comment: yes, `any` is preferable as it will short-circuit when a match is found, `max` will check every string every time.