# Time complexity of list and tuple lookup

Tags: python, list, tuples, time-complexity

`tuple` and `list` both have constant time `O(1)` for searching an element, but is it a different constant time for each?

Let's say I have two variables

```
list1 = ["hello", "how", "are", "you"]
tuple1 = ("hello", "how", "are", "you")
```

Is there a different constant time for searching in lists:

```
if "you" in list1:
    print "Found"
```

vs. tuples:

```
if "you" in tuple1:
    print "found"
```

Comment: Do read [Are tuples more efficient than lists in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/68630/4099593). For your particular example, tuple is twice as faster (0.07us vs 0.16us)

Comment: @BhargavRao Why does the python website list it with `O(1)` efficiency? along with lists? maybe a different constant time for each?

Comment: Afaik, Using `in` is O(n) efficiency. (Set is O(1)). If you feel that the dupe target does not answer, then please do mention. I will re-open it (But I am sure it will be closed again as it is a very similar question)

Comment: @BhargavRao Edited the question, please check and re-open

Comment: I edited the title and added a link to this question in the chatroom. Certainly, your question will be answered in a few minutes.

Comment: But please add a link to where ever you found the time complexity

Comment: Neither is technically O(1) in lookups, although tuples are often considered to be length-bound and thus tuple-lookups could be considered to be "more" O(1) than list lookup

Comment: *"tuple and list both have constant time O(1) for searching an element"* - no, they don't. *"Why does the python website list it with O(1) efficiency?"* - **where** does it do that? *"is it a different constant time for each?"* - big-`O` only allows broad, worst-case comparisons, different implementations may have very different fixed costs for the same scaling factor (and note that e.g. `O(3n)` and `O(2n)` are considered `O(n)`).

Comment: I got 88ns vs 90.5ns for tuple1 vs list1 using  Python 2.7.10 %timeit and substituting pass for print "found. With Python 3.4.3 they both took 136ns.

Comment: Where did you read that list has O(1) for searching an element? In https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity it says that the x in s operation is O(n)

Comment: @YuppieNetworking  Yes, it is. My mistake. I was quick to assume "Get Item" as search complexity

Comment: Ah, Apologies, Closing this question

Comment: Just to clarify, when we are using "in" operator to check if an element exists, the time complexity for both Lists and Tuple is O(n) but in general tuple is faster due to a lower constant factor? Am I correct?