# How does Python implement random.choice() from a set?

Tags: python, algorithm

I was curious: how does Python implement random.choice() from a set ?

I can imagine a very slow solution : choose a number n between 1 and len(set) and then iterate n times and return the item.

Comment: Have you actually tried to do `random.choice()` on a set? You'll find that sets are not supported.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L250-L256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.choice()` does not actually support sets:

```
>>> import random
>>> s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> random.choice(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/random.py", line 256, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

You can, however, convert the set to a list:

```
>>> random.choice(list(s))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets do not support object indexing. So you need to convert.
Using a tuple instead of a list is more efficient for instantiation:

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print random.choice(tuple(s))
```

If you are looking for clarity, an alternative choice is to use sample. However, it is not very efficient as internally as the first example it does convert anyway.

```
s = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print random.sample(s, 1)
```

ref:
[Are tuples more efficient than lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python)