# making a list of lists and strings into a flat list

Tags: python, list

I have the following `lista` that contains lists and strings:

```
['IBERDROLA', 'ACCOR\xa0SA', ['ADMIRAL'], ['ADECCO', 'IAG']]
```

I would like to make it a `flat_list` with this output:

```
['IBERDROLA', 'ACCOR\xa0SA', 'ADMIRAL', 'ADECCO', 'IAG']
```

Probably I might not be using the correct keywords to find the desired answer, buy I only found 
[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)
 (with no `str` like mines) into a `flat_list` which gives the following output:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in lista for item in sublist] 

['I', 'B', 'E', 'R', 'D', 'R', 'O', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'O', 'R', '\xa0', 'S', 'A', 'ADMIRAL', 'ADECCO', 'IAG']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list is stored as variable `l`, you can use a ternary operator with a test of `isinstance` as a condition:

```
[i for s in l for i in (s if isinstance(s, list) else (s,))]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to post, but any particular reason why `(s,)` and not `[s]`?

Comment: Only because tuples have [slightly less overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python) than lists, so unless it's meant to be mutated, I prefer using tuples whenever possible.

Comment: FWIW, this happens to be noticeably slower than a simple loop, perhaps due to the nested generator expression and building tuple objects for each string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isinstance()` function to check the type of a list item:

```
lista = ['IBERDROLA', 'ACCOR\xa0SA', ['ADMIRAL'], ['ADECCO', 'IAG']]
flat_list = []

for item in lista:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        flat_list.extend(item)
    else:
        flat_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   lst = ['IBERDROLA', 'ACCOR\xa0SA', ['ADMIRAL'], ['ADECCO', 'IAG']]
   new_lst = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[val if isinstance(val,list) else [val] for val in lst])
   print new_lst

   Result : ['IBERDROLA', 'ACCOR\xa0SA', 'ADMIRAL', 'ADECCO', 'IAG']
```