# If statement where if 3 of 5 conditions are true in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was wondering how to have an if statement in python that will react to any 3 out of 5 conditions being true to make the if statement true.

```
    if (a>2) and (b>3) and (c>2) and (d>6) and (e>4):
       list.append(True)
```

This code would add true to the array "list" if all 5 conditions are met but I was wondering how to get it to work if any 3 of the 5  are true to then append true to "list"?

Comment: You could use the ```or``` Operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
values = [a>2, b>3, c>2, d>6, e>4]
if sum(values) >= 3:
    list.append(True)
```

Just copying what @Blckknght said in the comments b/c I can't explain it better.  This works because:

> `True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0` (the `bool` class is a subclass of `int`)

`sum` sums numbers, so you check for a sum of booleans >= 3!

Comment: You might want to explain that this works because `True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0` (the `bool` class is a subclass of `int`).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Tom 's answer but with using tuples that leads to (maybe) faster construction, garbage collection and (maybe) a nicer syntax.

```
if sum((a > 2, b > 3, c > 2, d > 6, e > 4)) >= 3:
        lst.append(True)
```

Comment: The syntax might be nicer (depending on your preferences) but I doubt it will be faster.

Comment: Nothing is referencing the tuple being created external to the ```sum``` function, so as far as reference counting that is a plus. I don't know enough about tuples in python (I'm more of a c++ guy) but I'd imagine that an immutable data structure is cheaper to construct than a list. Edit: I looked it up, and it is *usually* indeed *slightly* faster: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python