# What's the pythonic way to order exactly two values?

Tags: python, sorting

I have two numeric values with the names `a` and `b`.

I want to assign the name `low` to the smaller value and the name `high` to the larger value.
What's the pythonic way to do this?

I considered

```
low, high = sorted([a, b])
```

but that seems overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it be overkill? `sorted` is explicit, efficient and concise.

Just use: `low, high = sorted([a, b])`

Answer (score 1):

Talking about pythonic **and** performance, you could write `low, high = sorted((a, b))`, because tuples are almost always more performant than lists, but that's really a micro optimization.

Other than the call to BUILD_TUPLE instead of BUILD_LIST, there's no difference.

Here's the proof:

```
import dis
import timeit

print("list:")
dis.dis("low, high = sorted([a, b])")
print( timeit.timeit("[a, b]", setup="a,b=1,'x'", number=10000000) )
print("-"*60)
print("tuple:")
dis.dis("low, high = sorted((a, b))")
print( timeit.timeit("(a, b)", setup="a,b=1,'x'", number=10000000) )
```

Output:

```
list:
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sorted)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)     
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)     
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_NAME               3 (low)   
             14 STORE_NAME               4 (high)  
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)  
             18 RETURN_VALUE
0.47138820000000003
------------------------------------------------------------
tuple:
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sorted)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              2
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             12 STORE_NAME               3 (low)
             14 STORE_NAME               4 (high)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
0.3673789999999999
```

Related: [Are tuples more efficient than lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python)

Comment: What Python version did you use? I tried 3.10.2 and both seemed equally fast.

Comment: @KellyBundy I've been running it with Python 3.9.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
low, high = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)
```

Comment: This *is* faster than `sorted`, but it's also more verbose and more error-prone. This isn't going to be your bottleneck, so just going with `sorted` is probably better.